# Searching and Filtering a Table through Asp.Net / MVC

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc

I am following this [Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page) to implement a table in MVC ASP.Net that will allow users to filter and search through a list of jobs as well as allowing them to edit and add news jobs.

Here is my code so far, I have modified it slightly from the tutorial to suit my needs:

```
@model IEnumerable<JMWebApp.Models.Job>

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "Job Manager";
}   

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["IdSortParam"]">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)</a>
            </th>
            <th>
                <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["ReferenceSortParam"]">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Reference)</a>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var job in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => job.Id)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => job.Reference)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my C#:

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder)
{
    var filteredJobs = ReturnJob();

    ViewData["IdSortParam"] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "id_desc" : "";
    ViewData["ReferenceSortParam"] = sortOrder == "Reference" ? "reference_desc" : "Reference";

    switch (sortOrder)
    {
        case "id_desc":
            filteredJobs = filteredJobs.OrderByDescending(j => j.Id).ToList();
            break;
        case "Reference":
            filteredJobs = filteredJobs.OrderBy(j => j.Reference).ToList();
            break;
        case "reference_desc":
            filteredJobs = filteredJobs.OrderByDescending(j => j.Reference).ToList();
            break;
        default:
            filteredJobs = filteredJobs.OrderBy(j => j.Id).ToList();
            break;
    }
    return View(filteredJobs);
}
```

The call to `ReturnJob()` is a simple `MySQL` statement that returns a list of `Jobs`. As the tutorial uses Entity Framework, I am having a few issues. Clicking on the heading links does not sort the data by either column, ascending or descending - really nothing seems to happen.

Secondly, even if that did work I'd be making a call to the MySQL database and retrieving around 1000 jobs every time someone filtered or searches the data. I'd rather store the `Jobs` and then work off of a different List when filtering/searching.

As I'm completely new to Asp/MVC I'm a little confused as to how to move this all out of my Index() Method. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: use a client-side table plugin such as FooTable, or tableSorter, or DataTables, which all have built-in filtering and sorting functionality without having to refresh the page or refresh the data. You can supply all the data up front (they usually have a realistic limit on what they can handle, which is generally in the thousands of rows). That way, you can dispense with all your expensive server-side filtering and sorting, and barely have to write any code on the client side, either. You can google any of them easily, and there are others available besides what I've mentioned.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for the advice. I did start out with `DataTables` and got that working - however you have to pay for add/edit/delete functionality which I would want ideally. I'll check out the other two you suggested and hope they're free.

Comment: both are completely free as far as I know, and both are fairly extensible as well - I have added custom filtering UI to FooTable before now, for instance. http://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/